# Why can't this generic method return concrete class that implements it's interface?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I would like to return the concrete class 'CountryPage' from this method.

```
public Task<T> Build<T, T1>(T1 data, params object[] args) where T : ICountryPage where T1 : ICountryObject
{
    var page = new CountryPage();
    return Task.FromResult(page);
}
```

CountryPage implements interface ICountryPage therefore I would expect this method to be able to return it.

However I get the error: **Cannot convert expression type: System.Threading.Tasks.Task<CountryPage> to return type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>**

I don't want to include the concrete type in the signature as this class implements an interface with this signature.

For clarity, my countryPage class looks like this

```
public class CountryPage: ICountryPage{}
```

And I am calling it thus

```
var response = service.Build<CountryPage, CountryPageObject>(data, args);
```

As this is a new development I can change any of the interfaces to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the compiler doesn't know how to convert `Task<CountryPage>` to `Task<T>`, if you can guarantee that `T` must be `CountryPage`, then you can force the conversion.

```
public static Task<T> Build<T, T1>(T1 data, params object[] args) where T : ICountryPage where T1 : ICountryObject
{
    T page = (T)(ICountryPage)(new CountryPage());
    return Task.FromResult(page);
}
```

Comment: In my case I would be able to guarantee that so your example works for me. But I'm starting to wonder if have approached this the wrong way. Thanks @shingo

Comment: @Username_null: It does sound like the wrong approach, yes. A generic method that can only be called with one set of type arguments would be better off being non-generic. (To put it another way: why not just change it to `public static Task<CountryPage> Build()`? (Do whatever you need to with the arguments, that's a different matter.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet. It's come about as I am experimenting with factories to improve the codebase but in reality I think I am making it harder work than it needs to be! Or I need a better understanding of factories in general.

Comment: @Username_null If you cannot change the method signature, then this is what you can do. But usually you should have another factory that create instances of `ICountryPage`, so the implementation of the `Build` method becomes `var page = (T)factory<T1>(data)`. The question is not about how you call the method, but why you can't change the sig.

Comment: @shingo As I am still learning factories I have let this one go until I fully understand them and how to apply them to the project I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

I can define my own type:

```cs
class MyType : ICountryPage {...}
class MyOtherType : ICountryObject {...}
```

Now I can call `Build<MyType, MyOtherType>()`, and I expect to get a `Task<MyType>`.

But a `CountryPage` is not a `MyType`, and a `Task<CountryPage>` is not a `Task<MyType>` (with or without variance rules) - hence the compiler error.

Comment: Not sure I understand. 

In my case I have

class CountryPage : ICountryPage {...}
class CountryPageObject: ICountryPageObject {...}

I call it by using Build<CountryPage, CountryPageObject>() and do expect to get a response of Task <CountryPage>;

Is that not the same as you are suggesting

Comment: @Username_null: Imagine Marc's code, and a call to ``Task<MyType> task = Build<MyType, MyOtherType>(...)`. What do you expect that call to do? Your implementation tries to return a `Task<CountryPage>`, but that doesn't match `Task<MyType>`... so what would you expect to happen at execution time? The compiler error is preventing this sort of situation. (It's not about the specific example you've said which *would* work - it's about all the other cases where it *wouldn't* work.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Thanks for clarifying. As mentioned in the other answer I think it may be that it's my approach that's at fault here.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of

```
public Task<T> Build<T, T1>(T1 data, params object[] args) where T : ICountryPage where T1 : ICountryObject
```

Expects `data` to be of `T1`, `params` to be `object[]` and it is to return a `Task<T>`. If you return `Task.FromResult(new CountryPage())` as you did, then you have a `Task<CountryPage>` and not `Task<T>`. Instead:

```
public Task<T> Build<T, T1>(T1 data, params object[] args) where T : ICountryPage where T1 : ICountryObject
{
    var page = new T();
    return Task.FromResult(page);
}
```

or

```
public Task<T> Build<T, T1>(T1 data, params object[] args) where T : ICountryPage where T1 : ICountryObject
{
    var page = new CountryObject();
    return Task.FromResult((T)(ICountryPage)page);
}
```